# How does it work to subscribe two times to the same method but with different param?

Tags: angular, observable

if I use a method like the following two times, one time with "a" as columnSelector and one time with "b" as columnSelector:

```
public getSomething(columnSelector: string): Observable<Something[]>
```

how will .subscribe() work with this?

Will it understand which fetched object belongs to the getSomething("a").subscribe() and which to the getSomething("b").subscribe() "stream" ?
Or will any getSomething("x") will trigger both subscribe() ?

I tryed this but I get a strange error (and Im not sure if this is caused by the double subscribe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to subscribe twice and decide what you want to do in the subscribe body for each fetched data.

For example :

```
dataA: Something[];
this.getSomething(a).subscribe((fetchedData: Something[]) => dataA = [...fetchedData]);

dataB: Something[];
this.getSomething(b).subscribe((fetchedData: Something[]) => dataB = [...fetchedData]);
```

Comment: Ok, thats exactly what I was doing and I interprete your answer in the way that this is working perfectly and angular isnt mixing up between getSomething(a).subscribe and getSomething(b).subscribe, thank you

Comment: you're right. these are two separate streams of data which won't mix up.

Answer (score 0):

some thing like [this](https://angular.io/guide/http#why-write-a-service)

```
getSomething(columnSelector: string) {
  this.configService.getConfig()
    // clone the data object, using its known Config shape
    .subscribe((data: Config) => {this.config = { ...data }
      this.config.columnSelector = columnSelector;
});
}
```